# Entity Framework Contains vowels and consonants problem

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to match vowels and consonant search.

For example, we will search this word -->> "I am a computer engineer".
Entity Framework Contains methods should be matching those are words;

"I AM A COMPUTER ENGINEER"
"I am a computer engıneer" --> warning 'ı' not 'i' should must be matching. Or any vowel or consonants word.

For example, -->> any words "ÜÖÇşiğ".

Should must be matching -->>

"uocsİg" or "UOCSIG" etc.

this is my code bellow

```
var Customers = _unitOfWork.Customers.GetAll().Where(x => x.nameSurname.ToLower().Contains(customer.nameSurname.ToLower())).ToList();
```

Comment: Please phrase your question as an actual question. It makes it clear that you're asking on how to compare strings with insensitivity to accented characters (and casing, which you've already solved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only depends on the collation setting of your database.

If you are using mssql: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15

Accent sensitive:

> Distinguishes between accented and unaccented characters. For example, "a" is not equal to "ấ". If this option isn't selected, the collation is accent-insensitive. That is, SQL Server considers the accented and unaccented versions of letters to be identical for sorting purposes. You can explicitly select accent insensitivity by specifying _AI.

Case sensitive:

> Distinguishes between uppercase and lowercase letters. If this option is selected, lowercase letters sort ahead of their uppercase versions. If this option isn't selected, the collation is case-insensitive. That is, SQL Server considers the uppercase and lowercase versions of letters to be identical for sorting purposes. You can explicitly select case insensitivity by specifying _CI.

Since EF is translated to actual queries, and there is no other SQL way to ignore accent, whereas there is to upper equivalent, any combination should be applied in the database layer.

Watch out for performance issues. Contains, starts with etc, tells the db underneath to do sequential scans, even on indexed columns. So be careful to filter large tables by something else first, where applicable.

Comment: I use to pamelo ef mysql on .net core 2.2, So there's no way to fix it?